# Unimodal Sequences

Tags: combinatorics

Define a unimodal sequence of weight $n$ as a sequence of positive integers $d_1d_2 \ldots d_m$ such that:

1. $\sum d_i = n$
2. For some $j$, we have $d_1 \leq d_2 \leq \ldots \leq d_j \geq d_{j+1} \geq \ldots \geq d_m$

And let a strict unimodal sequence have the same definition, except with < instead of $\leq$, and > instead of $\geq$.

In a textbook I see the following claim: **"It is easy to see that the number of unimodal sequences of weight $n$ with largest term $k$ is the coefficeint of $q^n$ in $\frac{q^k}{(1 -q)(1-q^2)\ldots(1 -q^k)(1-q^{k-1})\ldots(1-q)}$."** I don't see why the claim is true.

I see that in the denominator, the coefficient of a term $q^j$ must be: (number of strict unimodal sequences of weight $j$ with an even number of terms, each no larger than $k$) - (number of strict unimodal sequences of weight $j$ with an odd number of terms, each no larger than $k$). But I don't think this interpretation helps understand why the claim is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to write this generating function as
$$
\frac1{1-q}\cdot \frac1{1-q^2}\cdots \frac1{1-q^{k-1}}\cdot \frac{q^k}{1-q^k}\cdot \frac1{1-q^{k-1}}\cdots \frac1{1-q}
$$
Expand each factor as a geometric series:
$$
(1+q+q^2+\dots)\cdots (1+q^{k-1}+\dots)(q^k+q^{2k}+\dots)(1+q^{k-1}+\dots)\cdots(1+q+\dots)
$$
On the other hand, a unimodal sequence with highest term $k$ looks like
$$
(\text{sequence of 1s})(\text{sequence of 2s})\cdots(\text{sequence of $k-1$'s})(\text{nonempty sequence of ks})(\text{sequence of k-1's})\cdots
$$
Choosing the summand in each geometric series corresponds to choosing the number of repeated entries in each of these $2k-1$ sequences.

Comment: Thank you! I can see that in the unimodal sequence if we have $a_1$ 1's, $a_2$ 2's, and so on then you can simply choose the term $q^{a_i}$ in the first geometric series, $q^{2a_2}$ in the second geometric series, and so on, thus establishing a correspondence between a unimodal sequence and the product of sums.